# Base setup of include files overridden by vendor set of files in msbuild

Tags: msbuild

I have a base `/images/` folder included in my build file.
Then I have a `vendor` folder which contains some replacements/overrides for those images also in an `/images` folder.

Both should end up in the same destination path in the project.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="$(Base)**\*">
    <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="$(ProductDir)**\*">
    <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

If I have a file `images/groups/image1.png" in both`BaseDir`and`ProductDir` then I am getting a

`payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'images\groups\'`

error.

Is there a way to tell `msbuild` that the second included files override/replace the already included files? Maybe with an `exclude` clause?